# Strip HTML tags from filter with custom sType

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have a datatable which is defined as

```
        $('#group').dataTable( {
         "sDom": '<"H"fi>t<"F">', 
        "aaSorting": [ [2,'asc'], [1,'asc'] ],
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            {"aTargets": [ 0 ],      "sType": null,         "bSortable": false, "bSearchable": false },       
            {"aTargets": [ 1, 2 ],   "sType": "html",       "asSorting": [ "asc", "desc" ] },      
            {"aTargets": [ 3 ],      "sType": "gcse-grade", "asSorting": [ "desc", "asc" ] },      
            {"aTargets": [ "_all" ], "sType": "grade",      "asSorting": [ "desc", "asc" ] } 
        ],
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "bFilter": true,
        "bInfo": true,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bScrollAutoCss": true,
        "bScrollCollapse": true,
        "bSort": true,
        "oLanguage": { "sSearch": "_INPUT_" }
     }
    );
```

As you can see I have used custom sTypes called `grade` and `gcse_grade`.  I have custom sorting working fine using oSort.  However, when I create the table these columns sometimes have HTML tags within them.

How can I filter these so that it firstly strips the HTML tags from within.  i.e. so the filter only sees the text, not the tags (as I don't want the filter to pick up any ,  or  tags).

I have a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/peetz/5AFce/) here

Answer (score 2):

To strip html tags on filter search, you can use something like this:

```
"aoColumnDefs": [
    {   "aTargets": [0],
        "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
            if (type === 'filter') {
                return data.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
            }

            return data;
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is just for sorting purposes, try this:

```
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['gcse-grade-asc']  = function (a, b) {
    var x = $('<div />').append(a).text();      // append to div element and get [inner]text to strip tags
    var y = $('<div />').append(b).text();      // append to div element and get [inner]text to strip tags
    return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));  // sort like normal
};

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['gcse-grade-desc'] = function (a, b) {
    var x = $('<div />').append(a).text();      // append to div element and get [inner]text to strip tags
    var y = $('<div />').append(b).text();      // append to div element and get [inner]text to strip tags
    return ((x < y) ? 1 : ((x > y) ? -1 : 0));  // sort like normal
};

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['grade-asc']  = function (a, b) {
    var x = $('<div />').append(a).text();      // append to div element and get [inner]text to strip tags
    var y = $('<div />').append(b).text();      // append to div element and get [inner]text to strip tags
    return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));  // sort like normal
};

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['grade-desc'] = function (a, b) {
    var x = $('<div />').append(a).text();      // append to div element and get [inner]text to strip tags
    var y = $('<div />').append(b).text();      // append to div element and get [inner]text to strip tags
    return ((x < y) ? 1 : ((x > y) ? -1 : 0));  // sort like normal
};
```

If you need it for filtering (and sorting, et. al.), just use the `fnRowCallback` function instead to manipulate the actual content before the table is drawn:

```
"fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
    var gcse = $('td:eq(2)', nRow),     // cache lookup
        grade = $('td:eq(3)', nRow);    // cache lookup
    gcse.html(gcse.text());
    grade.html(grade.text());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I have the sorting functioning as expected using oSort, I just need the filtering to work but not to include any HTML tags in the filtered results.  I have tried the fnRowCallBack you suggested but I can't get it to function correctly.  Basically I need to strip html out of all columns if possible, no matter what their sType.

Comment: By not function correctly, what happens is that it strips all html before rendering, hence leaving all formatting, anchors, etc. out of the displayed table, but still includes them in the filter.  This is kinda the opposite of what I want to do .. if you see what I mean?  I want to maintain all rendered html, but strip it so that it doesn't appear to the filter.

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle with testing data (i.e., not real data but something that mimics real data)?

Comment: First time i've used fiddle - great resource!  Here's my example http://jsfiddle.net/peetz/5AFce/   The table is generated with a variable number of pupils/units, therefore the table could have any number of rows/columns.  You will see I am using <small> and <strong> for different reasons, and also have a few <span>'s and <a...>'s thrown in for good measure.