# jQuery data table filtering not working when comma is used

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables, filtering

I have a data table and I am trying to filter the rows using a filter string which has a comma in it.

This is one of the rows in data table:

**`User logged in from 1.1.1.1, agent Mozilla/2.0`**

When I try to filter using `1.1.1.1` the above row appears in the search result. However, when I try the filtering using `1.1.1.1,` it fails and the above row does not appear.

I tried **`enabling/disabling` the regex**, **smart filtering** etc to no avail.

**Update:**

This is the code I have for filtering:

```
this.$('.table-filter-field').on('input.my_datatable', function filterListener() {
                $($(this).data('table')).dataTable().fnFilter(this.value);
    });
```

Comment: is the  comma  breaking js ?. any error?

Comment: @zod Nope, no errors

Comment: is there a                                         before comma :-)

Comment: Can you post a working example here?

Comment: See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/98Lecvx2/1/ It is as you described and works just fine. Please post your code if possible.

Comment: @BumptiousQBangwhistle Thanks a lot for the fiddle. I am using `fnFilter` in my code which is not working on comma. Updated the code in the description

Comment: @BumptiousQBangwhistle Your fiddle is working even if I use `fnFilter`. https://jsfiddle.net/saicharanp/98Lecvx2/3/. I don't know why it is not working in my code

Comment: @user2133404 Look at this one:  https://jsfiddle.net/98Lecvx2/4/   Newer versions of DataTables have two functions - the "legacy" version, "dataTable" and the new version which is "DataTable" with a capital D.  This fiddle uses the legacy version (.dataTable) and fnFilter.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with your code so that we can see it not working?

Comment: @BumptiousQBangwhistle This is the fiddle which is not working: https://jsfiddle.net/98Lecvx2/9/ . I am using an older version of data table 1.9.4 which I believe is not working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If their **`comma (,)`** not break your string search into the row then maybe the search regex you work with is not responding well you can either check the following code which works for many of project of mine for row data search.

```
$('#search_field').keyup(function () { // Search field keyup event.you can use other event instead.

    var rex = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'i');
    $('.yourtable tbody tr').hide();
    $('.yourtable tbody tr').filter(function () {
         return rex.test($(this).text());
    }).show();

})
```

Answer (score 0):

The bold tag is what is preventing the search from working.

See this SO question:  [Strip HTML tags from filter with custom sType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970577/strip-html-tags-from-filter-with-custom-stype)

I use the method above in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/98Lecvx2/13/

This is the key code:

```
  "aoColumnDefs": [
    {   "aTargets": [0],
        "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
            if (type === 'filter') {
                return data.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
            }
            return data;
        }
    }
]
```

Note that the code was written to only work on the first column.  I've added another row with the first and second columns flipped (so the second column has <b>1.1.1.1</b>, in it), and it isn't displayed with the filter.  If you have HTML in all your columns and need to ignore all the HTML, you'll need the `aTargets` string to include all of them - `[0,1]` in the fiddle.